# Как организовать работу и взаимодействие?

Tags: postgresql, applet, java

Приложение будет applet, т.к. при работе нужна работа с usb и com. Необходима работа с удаленной БД. Как организовать работу и взаимодействие? Нужен ли spring mvc для этого, или можно как-то напрямую? Если чрез mvc то как сделать? Нигде не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Из апплета достучатся к этим устройствам навряд ли получится. У нас была необходимость работы со сканером, использовали внешние dll + сертификат.